# On Java class path, clarification needed

Tags: java, classpath

In the following scenario:

```
APP_HOME=/Users/me/Documents/workspace/Mimer/bin
javac -cp $APP_HOME/lib/*.jar::  BCClient.java
```

Assuming `$APP_HOME/lib` contains all the jars needed

What would cause the following:

```
BCClient.java:35: package com.thoughtworks.xstream does not exist
..
```

It looks like files libraries needed by the .java are not found, except that when i do the following code fails with the same error

```
javac -cp "$APP_HOME/lib/xstream-1.2.1.jar;$APP_HOME/lib/xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar"  BCClient.java
```

Comment: What is the use of `::` in the classpath? You don't need any `:` at the end, only as delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with a compiler Java 6+. But if you execute this command from a shell that perform wildcard expansion, then you need to put the wildcards in quotes. More details can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options).

/Library/Java/Home/bin/javac -cp "$APP_HOME/lib/*.jar:."  BCClient.java